# Meteor admin show collections from other packages

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections, cron

I'm trying to get have [Meteor Admin](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin) show the entries for [SyncedCron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron). Meteor Admin requires you to [attachSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) in order to register collections. I have done this with my own simple collections e.g. a basic events collection, but cannot work out how I might see SyncedCron jobs in the admin:

SyncedCron works quite well in my app. The docs say it "[uses a collection called cronHistory to syncronize between processes](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron)". If I run:

```
> SyncedCron._entries
   { name: 'LExXMbhKE7bJF5nay notification 2',
 schedule: [Function],
 job: [Function],
 _timer: { clear: [Function] } },
'LExXMbhKE7bJF5nay notification 3':
 { name: 'LExXMbhKE7bJF5nay notification 3',
  schedule: [Function],
  job: [Function],
  _timer: { clear: [Function] } } }
```

I check that cronHistory exists with:

```
Mongo.Collection.getAll();

{ name: 'cronHistory',
instance:
 { _makeNewID: [Function],
   _transform: null,
   _connection: [Object],
   _collection: [Object],
   _name: 'cronHistory',
   _driver: [Object],
   _restricted: false,
   _insecure: undefined,
   _validators: [Object],
   _prefix: '/cronHistory/',
   before: [Object],
   _hookAspects: [Object],
   after: [Object],
   hookOptions: [Object],
   direct: [Object] },
options: undefined }
```

So I try to attach a schema before registering it for Meteor Admin:

```
cronHistory.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
name: {
type: String,
label: "Name"
}
}));
```

And get error:

```
ReferenceError: cronHistory is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `SyncedCron` writes to the `cronHistory` collection but doesn't export the collection handle. According to [this](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron/blob/master/synced-cron-server.js#L89), the collection should be accessable via `SyncedCron._collection`.

Given that, you should be able to do:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  var root = Meteor.isClient ? window : global;
  root.CronHistory = SyncedCron._collection;
  root.CronHistory.attachSchema(...);
});
```

---

**updated answer**

Based on our conversation below, this is just a really hard problem. You have two packages and your app all defining and using collections, and the ordering needs to be precise for everything to work. Here's what I would do:

1. Define a `CronHistory` collection just like you wold any other in your app and attach the schema like normal.
2. Add `CronHistory` to your `AdminConfig` along with the rest of the collections in your app.
3. Use a [local version](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages) of `SyncedCron` and modify it to look for the globally defined `CronHistory` collection. See [this post](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/collections-by-reference) for some hints. Note you'll need to remove the `new Mongo.Collection(options.collectionName);` line.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that. It gives: `Error: A method named '/cronHistory/insert' is already defined`

Comment: Give the updated answer a try. It seems like that should work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I get `TypeError: Cannot call method 'attachSchema' of undefined`. However, in the meteor shell, autocomplete offers `attachSchema` if I tab with `SyncedCron._collection.`. So it feels closer, but still not there! Any other ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a load ordering issue, where the above code is running before the definition from `SyncedCron`. Is the above in a package or just somewhere in your app code? One thing to try is just wrapping it in a [Meteor.startup](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_startup)... though that may have other problems.

Comment: Wrapping in `Meteor.startup` seems to have taken me to the next stage. Now registering `cronHistory` with Meteor Admin leads to `cronHistory is not in the [object global]`. I've tried various other names for it, even trying: `cronCollection = SyncedCron._collection; cronCollection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema...`. What else could I try?

Comment: I don't know if I'm going to be able to get you out of this, but I'll keep trying. :) See the updated answer. I'm not sure if you need this on both the client and the server, so I wrote it in a generic way.

Comment: Thank you! But Meteor Admin still can't find my reference to cronHistory in `AdminConfig`, whether I use `root`, `CronHistory` or `cronHistory`. Error is `Error: cronHistory is not in the [object global]`, or with `root`, or `CronHistory`, depending on which I try. Any other ideas?

Comment: I had a look through the meteor admin source and I think the problem is with the way the package is designed. It expects a global variable (`AdminConfig`) to define the collections (this is an unfortunate API choice). You are probably setting that elsewhere and the meteor admin package is executing before your `Meteor.startup`, which means it can't find the collection. I'd say you should raise an issue, but that package doesn't look like it's in great health.

Comment: See the updated answer. I think your best bet is to override how SC works.

Comment: Many thanks! I'd rather use another Admin package for simplicity! Can you recommend one that would allow this functionality? And by the way, I can't thank you enough. Not the first time I've appreciated your Meteor advice either!

Comment: https://github.com/gterrono/houston picked up all collections automatically, including those mentioned above. Thanks again David!

Comment: Ah I was just about to suggest trying that! I'm glad you got it working. :)